# Suppose that $f(0) = 0$ and $f'(0)$ exists. Show that there is a function $g$ which is continuous at $0$ such that $f(x) = xg(x)$ for all $x$.

Tags: calculus

We know that $f'(x) = \lim \limits_{h \to 0} \frac{f(0+h) - f(0)}{h} = \lim \limits_{h \to 0} \frac{f(h)}{h}$ exists.

By our question, $g(x) = \frac{f(x)}{x}$.

$g(x)$ is continuos at $0$ iff $g(0) = \frac{f(0)}{0} = \lim \limits_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x}$.

I am not sure how to proceed from here and am not entirely sure if I was allowed to use to the definition of $g$ since it is ultimately what I am trying to prove.

Comment: Not much to prove here

Comment: Not quite. $g$ is undefined at $0$ as is. You need to fix that.

Comment: Define $g(0)$ as $f'(0)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments suggest, define $g(x) = \frac{f(x)}{x}, x \neq 0\;,\; g(0) = f'(0)$. Note that since $f$ was assumed to be differentiable at zero, we have 
$$ \lim_{x \to 0} g(x) =  \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x} = f'(0) = g(0) $$
Thus $g$ is continuous at zero. We also have that $f(x) = x \cdot g(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Thus $g$ satisfies our hypotheses and the theorem is proven.

Answer (score 0):

Define $g(x) = \frac{f(x)}{x}, \forall x \ne 0$ and $g(0)=f'(0)$. The $g$ function is continuous is $x=0$ by derivative definition.